# Numerical integration calculators

Tags: integration

How do computers/calculators computes definite integrals? They can not find an antiderivative and evaluate it. So then, what can we do?

Comment: Computers do not find integrals, they are just electronics. Computer programs do, which kind do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use approximation formulas, such as Riemman sums for example.

Answer (score 0):

Computer algebra systems can use Risch's algorithm to find the symbolic antiderivative. There are lots of algorithms to find numerical approximation of an integral.

Answer (score 0):

For the computation of definite integrals, computers basically do what you have been teached (some times the numerical methods are more complex but the spirit is just the same).

Did you have at any time the feeling that what they teach you is of absolutely no use ? If this is the case, I should really like to have examples from you since this is a very serious matter.

Be sure that I am very serious and not kidding at all.